# Convert hosted site to just parked domain

Tags: domain-name, domain-parking

I have a small site that's been a side project for a while and until I have an opportunity to improve it I'm going to take it offline. I'd still like to keep the domain name.

I've seen people buy domain names that get parked. What I haven't been able to find is how do you get a domain name you own and park it? The hosting service I'm using doesn't seem to offer that service so suggestions of services where I could move my domain to would also be helpful.

I'm doing this to save costs with hosting which I don't need ATM.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to setup parking or the like, simply ensure you have paid for the domain name and check the expiry date, provided you keep paying for the domain you will keep it.You will not lose your domain because there is not hosting assigned to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me revise. The place where I have it hosted (siteground.com) doesn't offer an option to simply park it. I expect a parked domain to be cheaper than a hosted one and I don't need the hosting portion ATM. So, I need to move my domain out of where it is to a service that accommodates parked domains but that were registered elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that the domain and the hosting are two seperate items. You do not need hosting to have a domain name, nor does it need to be parked to remain valid. Many people buy domain names simply to use names instead of IP's in the big wide world, or even just so the domain can recieve mail.
Long story short, as long as your pay for your DOMAIN it dosnt matter whether it is using a hosts name servers or an A record is pointing at hosting!

Answer (score 0):

While James is absolutely correct, you don't lose your domain if it's not hosted, you *might* want to consider an advertising parked domain.

[Google AdSense for Domains](http://www.google.com/domainpark/) could give you a little trickle of advertising revenue (or a river depending on traffic :D), and it's fairly easy to set up.

Additionally, the setup is just DNS updates which *should* be free through the registrar you got your domain through.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your registrar you can you their parking feature , or you can park it with a company like Google ads as said before or Sedo.